# Symfony2: URLs with trailing slash and an optional parameter

Tags: symfony, routes

I want all URLs in my application to have a trailing slash. I have the following route in my route.yml:

```
foo_route:
    pattern:  /foo/{page}/
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Foo:list, page: 1 }
    requirements:
      page:  \d+
```

Requests to '/foo/1/' work fine, however requests to '/foo/' are not matched because of the trailing slash in the URL pattern.

How can I define routes with trailing slashes and an optional parameter? I am aware I can define 2 different routes for the two cases, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Whats so bad about haveing another route?

Answer (score 7):

In a separate but related case, you can match the following three patterns:

```
/foo
/foo/
/foo/page/1
```

by eliminating the trailing backslash in the route and relaxing the regular expression to match 0 or more characters (*), instead of 1 or more (+):

```
foo_route:
    pattern:  /foo/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Foo:list, page: 1 }
    requirements:
      page:  \d*
```

However that will not match /foo/page/1/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its easier to define the Controller over an annotation.

in **route.yml**:

```
MineTestBundle:
    resource: "@MineTestBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Then you can define the route direct in your controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo")
 */
class FooController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_foo_index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{page}/", name="_foo_page")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function pageAction($page) {
        return array('page' => $page);
    }
}
```

Now when you try to access `/foo` you come to the **indexAction** and when you access `/foo/1/` you come to the **pageAction**.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've tried to reproduce your problem. The easiest way is to define 2 Routes in your config like this:

```
foo_route:
    pattern:  /foo/{page}/
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Foo:list }
    requirements:
        name: ".+"  

foo_route_foo:
    pattern:  /foo
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Foo:list, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        name: ".+"
```

In the Route without the parameter **{page}** You can set the page default to **1**.

But here in the Cookbook is a chapter [How to allow a "/" character in a route parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) so its possible to allow a **/** in the route so all that comes after `/foo/123/234/` is in the variable `$page` and you can split them for yourself in your function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but there is in fact only one action with an optional parameter page.

Comment: pageAction ;) there is the parameter. Its the same like your example but you have a default indexAction when you leave the parameter blank.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I want one route (with the optional parameter), pointing to one single action. I definitely want to avoid creating two routes and/or two actions.

Comment: @Gerry: Sorry for the misunderstanding i've reproduced your problem and edit my post.

Comment: Thank you, creating two routes is also the best solution I could come up with (as stated in the question), but also something I want to avoid. I suppose allowing a trailing slash inside the parameter itself is an option, but still a bit dirty.

Comment: @Gerry: Its really not the best way. But normally in the MVC pattern you don't put 2 Routes on one Action. But Perhaps there is a better way with more regex in the requirements.

Comment: @Gerry: Is your problem solved? Or do you need some more help?

Comment: no, for now I couldn't find any better solution than defining 2 routes, which I would like to avoid, as specified in the question.