# Add trailing slashes to symfony routing with optional pagination parameter of friendly URL

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have the following routing configuration:

```
# Resources/config/routing.yml
AcmeBundle_article:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing/article.yml"
    prefix:   /article

# Resources/config/routing/article.yml
acme_article:
    path:     /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Article:index, page: 1 }
```

Whenever I call `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_article'))` or `{{ path('acme_article') }}`, the URL goes without trailing slash `/` such as `example.com/article`. I want it to be like

`example.com/article/` <= default first page
`example.com/article/1`
`example.com/article/2`

When I changed the route without `{page}` parameter as below

```
# Resources/config/routing/article.yml
acme_article:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Article:index }
```

then, the trailing slash is added as what I expected:

`example.com/article/`
`example.com/article/?page=1`
`example.com/article/?page=2`

However, I want to keep `{page}` in the route and just want to add trailing slash only when there is no page parameter. Is it possible to do in Symfony 2 routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way that could fix this using a routing configuration, but I think it is not possible. However I got it working with a few tweaks.

**(1)** I added a variable `trailingSlash` in routing with a default value `/`. I use [KnpPaginator](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) for pagination. The default value `/` is required when the first page is paginated, otherwise the trailing slash is not appended in the URL.

```
acme_article:
    path:     /{trailingSlash}{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Article:index, trailingSlash: /, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        trailingSlash : '/?'
```

**(2)** I added some parameter processing in the `Article:index` controller. When the trailing slash is not found, throw an error.

```
public function indexAction($trailingSlash = null, $page = 1)
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    // if there is $page, $trailingSlash will be empty
    if (($trailingSlash == '/' && $page >= 1) || !is_numeric($page)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('No route found for "%s"', $request->getPathInfo()));
    }

    // ...

    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Article:index.html.twig', array(
        'articles'          => $articles,
        'pagination'        => $pagination,
        'totalArticles'     => $pagination->getTotalItemCount(),
        'trailingSlash'     => $trailingSlash
    ));
}
```

**(3)** I had to add a trailing slash to each URL generation in the controllers and twigs.

```
// Controller
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_article').'/');
// Twig
{{ path('acme_article') }}/
```

**(4)** From SEO perspective, I force to add trailing slash in `rel="canonical"` for `page=1`

```
{% block canonical %}
    <!-- trailingSlash is / when page = 1 -->
    <!-- trailingSlash is empty when page > 1 -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ url(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')) }}{{ trailingSlash }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

It fixed the problem, but I feel that it is a workaround. Better solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
# Resources/config/routing/article.yml
acme_article:
    pattern: /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Article:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page: ".*"
```

And in your controller :

```
// ArticleController.php
public function indexAction($page)
{
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }
}
```

Now you can access the route using :

```
/article   # page = 1
/article/  # page = 1
/article/2 # page = 2
```

**EDIT**

To keep the type hint of your parameter, just add a check in your method. example :

```
// Article:index
if ($page && intval($page) < 1) {
    return $this->redirect('/article/');
}
```

And you keep the trailing slash because `page` is not set.

**EDIT 2**

The following solution seems to be the cleaner.

```
# Resources/config/routing/article.yml
acme_article:
    pattern: /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Article:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page: \d*
```

This alternative allow a trailing slash and the `page`parameter must be a digit (if it is set).

It can solve your problem about allow slash in URL, but not automatically redirect if you doesn't add trailing slash manually at end of generated url (I understand it's not very clean but no other alternative found :/).

Comment: `page: ".*"` means that `page` is allowed for any character?

Comment: Yes, if you restrict parameter as digits only, it seems you can't have a trailing slash. With this (quick and dirty) alternative, you have to check the type of page parameter inside your controller, and use a redirection if it's not an int (look my edit for a working example).

Comment: You might misunderstand the question. The slash is automatically omitted by Symfony routing when we call `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_article'))` in controller or `{{ path('acme_article') }}`  in twig using the route key `acme_article`. We never ever use such `$this->redirect('/article/');`

Comment: ´$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_home_route') . 'article/');´ return the full URL with trailing slash. It's  the only alternative I know if you really need the slash, because it's seems to be not possible by define/generate url on Symfony.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the URL directly in controller such as `article/` since all routes are defined in one place i.e., `routing.yml`

Comment: I've update my answer to add digit requirement allowing trailing slash.
I understand your opinion about manually write URI but I think it's cleaner than define two routes for the same action (no other alternative found for your need). Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078348/4363634 and duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091518/symfony2-urls-with-trailing-slash-and-an-optional-parameter